# pandas read_excel as string with blanks values and strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel sheet that I need to read with a mixed data type column in the Tel# column. I have the Tel# column set as a text field in excel.

**sample data**

```py
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict({'SFDC ID': ['001','002', '003'], 'Name': ['company1', 'company2', 'company3'], 'Tel#': [pandas.np.NaN, '123-456-789',12345678.0]})
```

**required output**

The data from this sheet will be going into a SQL Server database, with the Tel# Series going into an nvarchar column. Missing values should go in as NULL, and the converted floating point numbers should go in as their string representation with no decimal place.
example SQL statement

```
INSERT INTO #table1 ([SFDC ID], [Name], [Tel#]) VALUES ('001', 'company1', NULL)
INSERT INTO #table1 ([SFDC ID], [Name], [Tel#]) VALUES ('002', 'company2', '123-456-789')
INSERT INTO #table1 ([SFDC ID], [Name], [Tel#]) VALUES ('001', 'company1', '12345678')
```

With the current insert, my SQL inserts the values as a floating point representation, due to missing values in my excel sheet.

```py
df = pandas.read_excel(filename, dtypes=str, sheet_name='Flatfile')

df = df.mask(df.isna(), None)
```

I've also tried converting to 'Int64' as that support NaN/NULL values, but obviously doesn't work with Tel# with dashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need missing values filled with `None` and all other values converted to strings. In this case you can use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with `None`:

```
df.astype(str).mask(df.isna(), None)
```

Example:

```
df
#   SFDC ID      Name         Tel#
#0        1  company1          NaN
#1        2  company2  123-456-789
#2        3  company3     12345678

df.applymap(type)
#         SFDC ID           Name             Tel#
#0  <class 'int'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'float'>
#1  <class 'int'>  <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>
#2  <class 'int'>  <class 'str'>    <class 'int'>

df.astype(str).mask(df.isna(), None)
#  SFDC ID      Name         Tel#
#0       1  company1         None
#1       2  company2  123-456-789
#2       3  company3     12345678

df.astype(str).mask(df.isna(), None).applymap(type)
#         SFDC ID           Name                Tel#
#0  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'NoneType'>
#1  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>       <class 'str'>
#2  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>       <class 'str'>
```

Comment: almost, the issue I'm still having is the numbers still contain the decimal place, and when read from the excel file rather than my mock data, the floating point numbers convert to the string representation '123456789.0' or '1.23456789e7'.